# svn export to checkout

Tags: linux, bash, svn

Had checked out an app. Then wanted an export of my working copy, was supposed to make a full copy, and then remove the .svn directories, but the mkdir failed and lost all the .svn in the main working dir.

Question : if i do a fresh checkout, is some version of find that can copy back only files edited after a certain date (from the exported to the new checkout dir tree), and more importantly - will this work? Any pit falls to look out for?

Edited files are all .xml or .java extension.

I was thinking about copying all files but then there are files changed by others., though I'm fairly certain that files that I have changed will be changed only by me.

Can do it manually but wanted to know if there was a nice script that will do major part of the grunt work.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you 1) checked out a source tree 2) edited files in the working copy 3) blew away one of the .svn directories. Instead of copying the files into a fresh checkout, why not just [restore the missing .svn directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96313/how-can-i-restore-svn-control-if-the-svn-folder-has-been-damaged)?

Comment: will try restore. not one .svn, all. used `find . -name ".svn"  -exec rm -fR {} \;`

Comment: Also, are you aware of the `svn export` command? It pulls down a clean source tree without the .svn directories so you don't have to resort to `find`.

Comment: yes i use export, but I wanted to export my own working copy, what I did not do (should have done) was make my own branch, commit to that, then export from there. For next time :-)

Comment: thank you  @thissuitisblacknot  this helped. did a force checkout and use diff too. If you make your comment an answer I will accept it as it did solve my issue, except for two places where I did not merge properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying the files you changed to a new location, you can simply [restore the  .svn directories you deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/96415/176646):

```
svn checkout --depth files --force URL PATH
```

where `URL` is the URL of your repository and `PATH` is the path to your working copy.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the diff and path util. I think it would work the most reliably. You can check out a fresh copy and then run diff between the two. This will create a patch that you can apply to the fresh checked out version.

```
diff -r --exclude=".svn" dir/one dir/two > patch.diff
```

Then in the check out version copy the patch.diff to the root of the fresh checkout and do

```
patch -p1 --dry-run < patch.diff
```

If this is happy then remove the `--dry-run` and it will apply the diff. This may be overkill but it is a good tool to have in the bag when things get really messed up.

Comment: hi Chris, thank you +1 your answer, Iam on a Mac desktop, when I run patch get messages such as:
    
    `can't find file to patch at input line 7 `
    
    `Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? `
    `The text leading up to this was: `
    `--------------------------`
    `|Only in /data/aos/w/a1/myapp: .project`
    
 I did a force checkout as suggested by @thissuitisblacknot and then manually resolved. Made a mistake there and then the diff that you suggested helped me see two changes.

Comment: Sorry it should probably be -p0. You probably don't need to prune off some of the path depending on where you created your diff. If you do a head on the diff you will see the path to the first file that was different between the two repositories. If the path is correct relative to the file location example not in ./someotherpath/foo.html then you don't need to prune the file. The -p flag is to prune off a part of the path from the diff file. For example -p1 would make ./tmp/foo.html just ./foo.html. Don't forget to remove the --dry-run if it says all parts applied successfully.